# Load shared assets between multiple entries in Webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webpack

I'm developing an app based on Node.js, Express and Webpack.

The application has multiple pages (with different client-side logic) so I'm using a custom structure folder, without a unique `/src` folder.

This is the structure:

```
|── clients
    └── client_1
        └── client_1_logic.js
        └── client_1_style.css
    └── client_2
        └── client_2_logic.js
        └── client_2_style.css

|── server
    └── index.js (node.js server entry point)
    └── other_serverside_stuff.js

|── public (public static folder)
    └── static_files (audio, img...)
    └── js (webpack bundled scripts)
        └── client_1.bundle.js
        └── client_2.bundle.js

|── shared (here's the question)
```

I'm happy with the current structure, cause I can separate the logic in a neat way, importing modules only when needed, bundling everything and putting it in the public folder, so I can retrieve the files runtime from the client-side.
The public folder is set to be a static folder with express: `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));`

What I want to do is to put some files in the `shared` folder (for example a common config file, ora a basic .css template), and import them in the client side logic.
For example, imagine a `config.js` in the `shared` folder, I would like to import it in `client_1_logic.js` this way:

```
// libs
import {html, render} from 'lit-html';
// style
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
// config
import config from './shared/config.js';

// do something with imported modules ...
```

Now I get the error `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './shared/config.js'`.

It works if I put the `shared` folder both in `client_1` and `client_2` subfolders, but I dont' really want to duplicate all the files.

Here's my `webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: {
    player: './clients/client_1/client_1_logic.js',
    controller: './clients/client_2/client_2_logic.js'
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public/js/'),
    publicPath: '/',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Many thanks in advance,
Francesco

Answer (score 2):

Okay I found a clean solution:

Adding a resolve rule to the `webpack.config.js` this way:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    config: path.join(__dirname, 'shared/'),
  }
}
```

I can import the file from clients this way:

`import config from 'shared/config.js'` (without `./`)

Here we go!